# How to write data from the accelerometer sensor on a file and write on matlab?

Tags: java, android, matlab, io, text-files

I want to collect data from the Android accelerometer and write it on a file. The file is stored on the SDCard and then I manually copy to the computer by adbpull comand. Then I want to analyze the values on Matlab.

What's the best way to do? I tried writting the parameters as a string but I dont know how to read then on Matlab.

```
        WriteOnFile(FdataAcc, String.valueOf(event.timestamp) 
                                + " " + mAcceleration[0] 
                                + " " + mAcceleration[1]
                                + " " + mAcceleration[2] + "\n");  

    public void WriteOnFile(File filename, String data){
    try{
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(filename,true));
        //new appended stream
        dos.writeChars(data);
        dos.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){;}

}
```

I also tried to write the values as float, but still I cant read on Matlab.

```
    public void WriteOnFile(File filename, long data){
    try{
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(filename,true));
        dos.writeFloat((float)data);
        dos.writeChars(" ");
        dos.writeFloat((float) mAcceleration[0]);
        dos.writeChars(" ");
        dos.writeFloat((float) mAcceleration[1]);
        dos.writeChars(" ");
        dos.writeFloat((float) mAcceleration[2]);
        dos.writeChars("\n");
        dos.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){;}

}
```

What's the best way to do? Should I use Dataoutputstream to write in a file? Sensor values are floats. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not familial with matlab,but I think you can export the data into CSV format quite easily, then you can manipulate the data in Excel (libraoffice, google docs) and then import it into matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the second example you showed, but don't write the characters between the floats.

When you do fopen on matlab, make sure you put in the machine format argument.  You might need to experiment with it until you get the right format, but it will work.  Do `help fopen` to see the options.

then all you have to do in order to read in all the data is

```
fid = fopen(filename,'r',MACHINEFORMAT);
data = fread(fid,inf,'float32');  %float32 is for single precision float
```

Or, if you want to read into an array:

```
data = fread(fid,[M,inf],'float32');
```

Where M is the number of elements in each column in the array.

Comment: I will have hundred of values, is there any way to get a file with 4columns x N rows (time mAccelerationX mAccelerationY mAccelerationZ)? How can read it on matlab? I want a matrix 4xN with all values.

Comment: The code I showed will read in all the data in the file (oops, I made a mistake, I will edit my answer).  After you read it in, you can resize data, `data = reshape(data,4,length(data)/4)`

Comment: Actually, there is an easier way to get the right size of the data, I will edit the answer one more time.

Comment: Thanks, fread with [m,n] is what I needed. Im trying to plot the data now.